# i don't know how to express summation in python gurobipy

Tags: python, optimization, gurobi

I have a variable like this Xitb.
I=[1,2],NC=['1'], NP=['2'] ,time=[1,...10], number=[1,..9]
when i is belong to NC, i want to express like this

`x111+x112+....x119<= 20`
`x121+x122+....x129<= 20`
...
`x1101+x1102+..x1109<=20`

i made code like this

```
import gurobipy as gp
from gurobipy import GRB 
m = gp.Model('Offshore')

xitb = m.addVars(NP, time,number, name = "preventive",vtype=GRB.BINARY)
addConstrs(gp.quicksum(xitb[i,t,b] for i in NC for t in time)<=20)
```

is it right code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two errors in your code:

1. You defined the first index of xitb as `NP` - I think you mean `I`
2. In the generator expression inside `gp.quicksum`, you're missing the 3rd index `b`

I believe  this will work:

```
xitb = m.addVars(I, time, number, name = "preventive", vtype=GRB.BINARY)
addConstrs(gp.quicksum(xitb[i,t,b]
                       for i in NC
                       for t in time
                       for b in number) <= 20)
```